# Swift 4 - How to create Custom SCNGeometry as polygon

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I've been trying to create a custom SCNGeometry polygon from a set of SCNVector3 positions with the following code:

```
private func polygonGeometry (vertices: [SCNVector3]) -> SCNGeometry {
        var indices: [Int32] = [Int32(vertices.count)]
        indices.append(contentsOf: generateIndices(max: vertices.count))
        let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices )
        let indexData = Data(bytes: indices,
                             count: indices.count * MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
        let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData,
                                         primitiveType: .polygon,
                                         primitiveCount: 1,
                                         bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
        return SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource], elements: [element])
    }
```

With this helperMethod for generate the correct amount of indices:

```
private func generateIndices(max maxIndexValue: Int) -> [Int32]{
        var counter: Int = 0
        var output: [Int32] = []
        while counter < maxIndexValue {
            output.append(Int32(counter))
            counter += 1
        }
        return output
    }
```

The code works fine for some polygons. However, sometimes I get the following error in console when trying to create a custom geometry, and the program crashes.

```
[MTLDebugDevice validateNewBufferArgs:options:]:467: failed assertion Cannot create buffer of zero length.
```

Does anyone have a clue why this happens? Is there any flaws in the code?

[EDIT]: I believe problem occurs when first position and last position has the same x,y,z values. Simply remove the the last position from the array of positions and the polygon should render as expected!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution? The suggestion in your edit did not solve my case.

Comment: @A.Claesson I think I did. If your polygon begins and ends at the same Vector3 position, it will crash. So, just remove the last Vector3 object from the array you are passing to the function and it would work. I've not experienced any crash since. Edit: Oh, the solution did not work for u? that's strange. Then I don't know..